# AJAX 403 Forbidden, only sometimes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Essentially I am trying to check if a username is taken, as the user types it fires the ajax and on keyup checks if it is taken, if it is it highlights the input red.  In Google Chrome I have the error console open and sometimes I am receiving the 403, and other times not.

I noticed the 403 when I start hitting delete or typing in the username too fast, other times it happens no matter what I do, and further yet, sometimes not at all.  The file permissions are OK and paths are correct (I think).  Any help is really appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#username").keyup(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/resources/ajax/userCallbacks.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'checkName='+$(this).val(),
            success: function(response){

                // Check response
                switch(response)
                {
                    case 'taken':
                        $("#username").addClass('red-border');
                        break;
                    case 'available':
                        $("#username").removeClass('red-border');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you should delay you ajax call with a `setTimeout` function, keeping the reference of the timeout. When a second event is fired before the the timeout has ended, you just ave to cancel the timeout (with `clearTimeout)` and recreate it. That will allow you to run the AJAX call only when the user has stopped to write a little, and then you will not have request flood problem.

Comment: Look into throttling and debouncing, you're killing your poor server. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it with a timeout, maybe you have to many requests in a short time...

```
var mytimeout = false;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#username").keyup(function()
    {
    if(mytimeout != false) {
        window.clearTimeout(mytimeout);
    }
    mytimeout = window.setTimeout("doAjaxRequest()",500);
    });
});

function doAjaxRequest() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/resources/ajax/userCallbacks.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'checkName='+$("#username").val(),
            success: function(response){

                // Check response
                switch(response)
                {
                    case 'taken':
                        $("#username").addClass('red-border');
                        break;
                    case 'available':
                        $("#username").removeClass('red-border');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Not sure that `$(this).val()` will return the value, as you are not in the right context.. YOu have to use `$("#username").val()`

Comment: Excellent, Thank you both!  I will be certain to utilize this in my future code.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet I have been using, that prevents too many request to be fired simultaneously.

The idea is you store the state of the ajax call in this.ajax. Once a new call is requested the previous one will be immediately cancelled, thus preventing overload of the webserver.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#username").keyup(function()
    {
        if( this.ajax )
        {
            this.ajax.abort();
        }
        this.ajax = $.ajax({
            url: '/resources/ajax/userCallbacks.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'checkName='+$(this).val(),
            success: function(response){

                // Check response
                switch(response)
                {
                    case 'taken':
                        $("#username").addClass('red-border');
                        break;
                    case 'available':
                        $("#username").removeClass('red-border');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```